# Search like gsmarena ajax search box for laravel with json input

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel, search

[gsmarena search box results picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvZg5.png)

Hello, I need a plugin for my laravel project for header search. I need the search box to search in ajax mode and looks like gsmarena (results have title, image and they are linked to a specific page). I provide the input by json.

I will be thankful if you help for solving it.

Thanks